# How to ensure that the secondary monitor mirrors the primary monitor before login?

Tags: login, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I use Ubuntu 18.04. I have connected secondary monitor(TV monitor) to my laptop using HDMI cable in mirror mode.Everything works almost fine except for two issues, one of which I will discuss here.

After reboot before login the TV monitor doesn't show the login screen(it shows blank purple screen) but the laptop shows the login screen. On investigation I found that, before login ,the secondary monitor is joined to the primary monitor. It does not mirror.Once I login to the system, Secondary monitor mirrors the primary monitor as expected.This is undesirable.

How can I ensure that before login the secondary monitor mirrors the primary monitor?

Comment: Following command should work but I do not know where to put it so that it gets executed before the user logs in : xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --same-as eDP-1-1

Comment: Found the answer. Please close it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/11738/force-gdm-login-screen-to-the-primary-monitor