# 2 Montitors and sign in is on secondary

Tags: boot

I have 2 monitors and when I turn on my pc the second monitor has the sign in but the mouse is on the primary what can I do to fix this.
I have a RTX 3080 in case you would need to know that, I did check the Navidia setting

Also I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with the Cinnamon desktop

Comment: If you're using GDM3 see https://askubuntu.com/questions/11738/force-gdm-login-screen-to-the-primary-monitor

Comment: I already read that and had no luck with any one of the solutions on that thread, that's when I posted this, especially since that is an older thread. But thank you for responding

Comment: Please edit your question then stating what you have tried and any errors that you are getting.  Unfortunately without details we can only guess.

Comment: Also, in that link I posted it still works, but you need to have the GNOME Desktop still installed and you do the settings from the GNOME Desktop as that will create that `monitors.xml` file that then gets copied to the `~gdm/.config` folder.  Expanded that is the `/var/lib/gdm3` folder.

Comment: The Gdm3 folder is there but the only file in it is greeter-dconf-defaults, and no other folders either. I never liked Gnome so I alway's install Cinnamon as soon as I do a new install.

Comment: This is not a huge problem, as all I do when I turn on my Pc is hit the space bar and sign in then everything is normal, So if it's not a simple solution then I'm not going to worry about it, Hopefully with Navidia releasing the source code some of these issues will be solved. I do tend to have to find my way around problems because of not using Gnome, so it is what it is. I really appreciate your time, Thanks